# ckeditor 3 - dialog - browse server - Cannot read property getSelection of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor, fckeditor

I try to set the selected path from "Browser Server" to the 'url' input-field as follows

```
var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
    dialog.setValueOf( 'info', 'url', url );
```

That works so far and the selected path will be displayed in the 'url' input-field BUT when i press "OK" i get this error-message:

```
ckeditor.js:415 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined
```

---

config.js

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {

var dialogName = ev.data.name; 
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition; 
var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();


CKEDITOR.tools.addFunction( SetUrl );

if(dialogName == 'link') { 

       dialogDefinition.onLoad = function ( ) { 
    }; 

    dialogDefinition.onShow = function () { 
        dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
        elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','anchorOptions');    
        elem.getElement().hide();
        elem = dialog.getContentElement('info','emailOptions'); 
        elem.getElement().hide();
    }; 
}

});


function SetUrl(url)
{
    var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
    dialog.setValueOf( 'info', 'url', url );
};
```

---

test.html - javascript-call

```
parent.opener.SetUrl(filename);
```